# Problem installing .deb in Software Install Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: software-installation, dpkg, software-center, deb, 20.04

I tried to install some `.deb` files in Ubuntu 20.04 from GitHub and other internet sources, but when I open it with Software Install it gives me [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DQVSy.jpg) problem (*Failed to install file: not supported*). The only way for me to install them is to go to the downloaded file and do `sudo dpkg -i file.deb`.

Can anyone help? I don't know what to do and I don't want to use the terminal every time.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks

**EDIT:** that's NOT a problem with .deb in Ubuntu, it is a problem with Software install. I can install every .deb through the terminal but not with Software install, and Ubuntu suggests to install .deb with Software install. That's not a dependencies problem or anything similar, that's an issue with installing .deb WITH Software install and I would like to know how I can fix Software installer

Comment: I install only software that I trust and know. I just don't want to install it from terminal because from software install it's easier and faster

Comment: what if I need to install a 3rd party software with a .deb? Until 3 days ago everything was ok

Comment: I would anser that you install it using a terminal and see what is the problem. It a terminal you see the output. It is really faster and more clear. When you blindly try to install a deb from GUI, you don't see if there is any trouble.

Comment: yes, I've done it, but the problem is that from terminal it installs it without any problem or error.  I don't have problems installing .deb, I've problems installing it from software install when i shouldn't have problems. So the problem is in software install.

Comment: You can report a bug if you like. But that app IS NOT DESIGNED to install each and every deb.

Comment: so why until a few days ago he did install them without problems? it says file not supported, but it was supported until a few days ago and i don't think ubuntu suggests you to install .deb from software install when software install cannot install them

Comment: You should rather use `sudo apt install ./my_filename.deb` than `dpkg` directly. That way it can do dependency resolution etc. properly, which `dpkg` does not. Note you need an absolute or explicit relative (i.e. starting with `./`) path for `apt`, so that it can distinguish if it is a file or a package name.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### The Problem

Ubuntu 20.04 has two 'Software Install' applications, one is `gnome-software` and the other is `snap-store`, installed by Canonical via snap. This snap app software centre has the problem installing local files from the `/tmp` directory. Can be easily verified by running these commands:

```
gnome-software --local-filename '/tmp/mozilla_user0/app_amd64.deb' 

snap-store --local-filename '/tmp/mozilla_user0/app_amd64.deb'
```

The snap-store command will error with `Failed to install file: not supported`

### Workarounds

You can install **gdebi** or similar software as suggested in other answers but there is a workaround to modify the file association to use the other **Software Install** which is associated with `gnome-software`:

#### Firefox

When choosing application to open change for the suggested or default *Software Install* to the other further down the list. This second one is the *gnome-software* association.

[image]

You can verify that it is *gnome-software* in *Preferences->Applications*:

[image]

#### Nautilus

The same can be done within Nautilus by right-clicking and opening *Properties* for a */tmp/.deb* file and switching the *Open with* from current default *Software Install* to the other suggestion.

[[image]]

Answer (score 134):

If you are using firefox, and opted to download and open the file with Software Install, what has likely occurred is the file has been downloaded into the `/tmp/mozilla_userX` directory, from which the Ubuntu Software Installer is not able to install anything.

Opting to save the file first before opening with Software Install should solve this issue.

For files that have already been downloaded, moving the file out of the `/tmp/mozilla_userX` directory into a sub-directory of `/home/user/`, e.g. `Downloads`, should solve the problem.

Comment: I've had similar problems myself with those .deb packages, but it worked after I moved the file. Something like slack or mtpaint should be safe?

Comment: Any idea why Ubuntu Software Installer is not able to install anything from /tmp/mozilla_userX? Tried to google but with no effect.

Comment: in Ubuntu 20.04 I can't install even having the file in Downloads

Comment: @Kostanos yes, you can install .deb files from your own downloads directory.

Comment: Bug report at https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bug/1908469

Comment: The snap store as a snap isn't going to have access to the share /tmp so that would be an issue yes

Comment: +1 solution works and answers OP's question regarding why the installation doesn't work. This should be the accepted answer

Comment: I had the same problem with a file sitting on an smb share. Copying the file locally solved it.

Comment: This is the correct answer, at least for 20.04. Firefox download .deb to /user/tmp, even though I instructed it to save to Downloads. After move it to downloads, the deb installer can install it.

Answer (score 38):

If you're looking for a reliable GUI way to install .deb files, use `gdebi`.

To see if you already have it installed on your system...

```
dpkg -l gdebi | grep ii
```

If it's not there, install it this way...

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gdebi
```

Then get the "Properties" of any .deb file, and set the default "Open With" application as `gdebi`. Now you can just double-click on .deb files to install them.

[image]

**Note**: `gdebi` may not operate properly if .deb files are on the desktop.

**Update #1:**

`gdebi` is broken in Ubuntu 21.04.

Comment: @fedeUbuntu You can't. This is probably the best answer you're going to see.

Comment: @fedeUbuntu I believe that in 20.04 `Ubuntu Software/Software Center` has been slanted towards snap apps, but I can't say for sure, as the option to install 20.04 hasn't popped up on my system yet :-(

Comment: Can you explain how `gdebi` is better than the "Software Install" option I see in the menu there too? Is it better?

Comment: Nevermind: the edit in the question indicates Software Install doesn't work here, so apparently "GDebi Package Installer" does work in cases where "Software Install" fails. Do you know why gdebi works in cases where Software Install fails?

Answer (score 12):

I'm experiencing the same problem, but if in the browser I choose "Save file" rather than "Open with: Software Install", then right click the saved file and open with Software Install, it works (it doesn't work with Ubuntu Software directly in either case).

Afaict, Software Install is part of Ubuntu Software

Answer (score 2):

Just moved to Ubuntu and I've also been bitten by this.

#### Solution 1

1. The easy solution like others have mentioned is just save it Downloads and then install using Software Install. Works fine.

#### Solution 2

1. create a folder in your home directory, eg `~/tmp`
2. issue a command `TMPDIR="~/tmp" firefox &`

Breakdown of command:
`TMPDIR="~/tmp"` is setting the `TMPDIR` env variable to a folder in home folder. `firefox &` is invoking firefox in the background. With this, opening a deb file via Ubuntu Software will now work as intended.

This only sets `TMPDIR` in firefox, so other programs will continue to use the canonical location of `/tmp`. You could set this in your bash if you wanted to, but I'm not sure of the ramifications of moving `/tmp` files. For example, you need to make sure the `~/tmp` files get deleted on reboot.

Personally I prefer to use the first solution, and just download my deb files under `Downloads/deb` for example. That way I can easily uninstall them using Ubuntu Software. Instead of fiddling with the command-line.

Answer (score 0):

This really is an issue with file association. For some reason the files .deb are not associated correctly. If you download the file, right-click, properties. Then go to the open-with tab and select the right file association (software install) then set as default. Try again.
In my case it even looked ok but I had to set to "Archive Manager" and set as default, confirm, get out, go back, set to "Software Install", make default, confirm and try again for it to work.
But then all is fine (both on a french and english install).
Solution was found here:
https://itsfoss.com/cant-install-deb-file-ubuntu/