# Why .deb file doesn't install directly, instead it opens in read-only mode when I double click?

Tags: software-installation, 22.04

When I double click on local .deb file it doesn't install directly, instead it opens in read-only mode in Ubuntu 22.04LTS (Screenshot attached). To install the same I have to right click on .deb file > open with other application. Then a recommended applications prompt opens. From there I select software install to install a software.

[image]

Comment: A *.deb* file is a compressed archive, and the file-manager program is treating it as such. eg. if I explore a .deb file it's contents are reported as `Debian binary package (format 2.0), with control.tar.xz, data compression xz` but it can't know what OS/release its for, as it may not be your own, so it's safer to treat it as what it is - a compressed archive.   (ps:  the .deb file I used as example is **not** for my OS/release system & I'd for one not want it installed automatically on click; not even attempted to install!)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ubuntu Software Center ("Software" program) and "Snap Store" missing on fresh Ubuntu 20.04 install (& can't install \*.deb files from GUI file manager)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1265806/ubuntu-software-center-software-program-and-snap-store-missing-on-fresh-ub) . The second half of the answer --adding Ubuntu Software as a default application for deb files-- seems like exactly what you seek.

Answer (score 2):

A *.deb* file is a compressed archive, and the file-manager program is treating it as such. eg. if I explore a .deb file it's contents are reported as

`Debian binary package (format 2.0), with control.tar.xz, data compression xz`

but it can't know what OS/release its for, as it may not be your own, so it's safer to treat it as what it is - a compressed archive.

ps:  *the *.deb* file I used as example is **not** for my OS/release system & I'd for one not want it installed automatically on click; not even attempted to install!*

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to install the dpkg file, you should try running this:

```
sudo dpkg -i ./myapp.deb
```

The above command installs the Debian package.

*A quick heads up: You should only install packages if you trust them.*