# Can't update local installed app from software center using deb file

Tags: updates, dpkg, software-center

I ran into an annoying problem trying to update an app with a downloaded deb file. First, the software center opened and said the file wasn't supported. I found through searching, the file wasn't in a location the app supported ([Problem installing .deb in Software Install Ubuntu 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1232868/problem-installing-deb-in-software-install-ubuntu-20-04)).

But after moving it from `/tmp` to `~/Downloads` I get a different problem, where it just takes me to an info screen, but because I have an earlier version installed (0.19) it doesn't given me the option to install it (see screenshot).

[image]

My workaround is just to run `sudo dpkg -i` from the command line, but it's really unfortunate that this flow doesn't just allowing updating. Is there some configuration that's broken?

Comment: https://blog.javinator9889.com/discord-ppa-keep-it-up-to-date-on-linux-easily/

Comment: What is wrong with first deleting your currently installed version then installing the downloaded .deb?

Comment: @user535733 I'm going from 0.19 to 0.21, that's an upgrade.

Comment: @vanadium, deleting the existing version isn't any easier than just doing `sudo dpkg -i`. The UX shows a "delete" trash icon, but that doesn't work since the software is already installed. It feels like a bug, but I'm surprised this isn't a problem for others. Hence, my question about my configuration or something.